# Disable windows keys in a node webkit application?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, keyboard-hook

One of my new application i need to disable window keys so,

Any one knows how to disable left and right window key in a node web kit application ?

Comment: in text area you want disable ?

Comment: i want to disable window keys while running node web kit application.start menu should not popup on press window key.                                                                                                               Thank you

Comment: i tried in javascript but able to disable

Comment: You are able to disable window key ??

Comment: no i can detect window key press but not able to disable its still show window screen

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: You can enable or disable the Windows key that is now available on many new computer keyboards. This key usually provides shortcut access to the Start button or other Windows functions. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyboard hooking is not possible with node js.you can create a low level keyboardhooking code in VC++ or c# and that run as a child process from nodewebkit

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as disabling keys that I know of but what you *can* do is assign "nothing" (no function) to whichever keys you want to "disable" like this:

(Just paste this code at the very top of your javascript)

```
document.onkeydown=KeyPress;

function KeyPress(e){

e=e||window.event;

if (e.keyCode=='37'){} else // Left arrow do nothing

if (e.keyCode=='39'){} else // Right arrow do nothing

if (e.keyCode=='27'){} // Esc do nothing, and so forth.

}
```

Comment: What on Earth is "window key"? Are you talking about the operating system or a Window.open() or what?

Comment: Meta key between cntrl and alt